# How proximity alert can trigger audio file

Tags: android, audio, broadcastreceiver

I have a small app where i can  obtain my location or set it up manually.That sets up proximity alert. As soon as I enter defined area (certain radius etc.) proximity alert receiver displays Toast message. Everything works fine, but... I also want onReceive method to play short sound and vibrate. Not sure if it is possible, so any help wold be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Following code crashes with error receiving broadcast intent blah-blah (has extras)...
Here is my Proximity receiver class:

```
package com.reminder;
public class ProximityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

  private static final Context Context = null;

@Override
 public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
 {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      String action = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;    // To deifine if user is leaving or entering 
      boolean state = arg1.getBooleanExtra(action, false);
      if(state)
  {
      // When entering area
    try {
        playBeep();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  


      Toast.makeText(arg0, "You have entered your area", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  }
  else
  {
      //When leaving area
      Toast.makeText(arg0, "You are leaving your area", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}

  public void playBeep() throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException {
        try
        {
             Uri myUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.reminder/res/" + R.raw.beep); // initialize Uri here
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText( Context, "exeption: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        };

    }

private Context getApplicationContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Logcat:

```
   04-29 20:28:42.925: D/ActivityThread(6597): BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=com.paad.trasurealert flg=0x10 (has extras) }, ordered=true,  receiver=com.reminder.ProximityReceiver@415d2568, IIntentReceiver=415c5630
  04-29 20:28:42.928: D/ActivityThread(6597): BDC-Calling finishReceiver: IIntentReceiver=415c5630
  04-29 20:28:42.928: D/AndroidRuntime(6597): Shutting down VM
  04-29 20:28:42.928: W/dalvikvm(6597): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cbd258)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.paad.trasurealert flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.reminder.ProximityReceiver@415d2568
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:755)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:233)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at com.reminder.ProximityReceiver.playBeep(ProximityReceiver.java:70)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at com.reminder.ProximityReceiver.onReceive(ProximityReceiver.java:32)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:746)
  04-29 20:28:42.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6597):   ... 9 more
```

Comment: Post the logcat showing the stack trace for when you get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `playBeep()` method you have this line...

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
```

...but your `getApplicationContext()` method returns `null`...

```
private Context getApplicationContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Get rid of that method. You are already being given a `Context` instance as the `arg0` parameter of `onReceive(...)`. Change your `playBeep()` method to be something like...

```
public void playBeep(Context context)
```

...then in `onReceive(...)` call it using...

```
playBeep(arg0);
```

...and in the method itself, call...

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, myUri);
```

Also in your `catch` block of that method, this is wrong...

```
Toast.makeText( Context, "exeption: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

...change `Context` (upper-case 'C') to `context` (lower-case 'c').

Comment: Right.. I did that and now getting NullPointerExeption at : Toast.makeText( context, "exeption: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: It is true that sometimes to get the code working just need a little sleep.)))